# Irreducible polynomial proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Prove that $$2x^6+12x^5+30x^4+60x^3+80x^2+30x+45=0$$ has no real roots.

I think we need to prove this through Eisenstein's Irreducibility criterion, but I am unable to apply it correctly.

Let $a_0, a_1, ... ,a_n$ be integers. Then, '''Eisenstein's Criterion''' states that the polynomial
$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ ... + a_1x+a_0$ has an irreducible factor of degree more than $k$ if:

$ 1) p$ is a prime which divides each of $a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_{k} $

$ 2) a_{k+1}$ is not divisible by $ p$

$ 3) a_0$ is not divisible by $p^2$

How do we use the above here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126715/discussion-on-question-by-user112196-irreducible-polynomial-proof).